# Pinch Zoom - not able to keep the image position fixed on zooming

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, zooming, pinchzoom

I am new to iphone development. I want zoom an imageview , I am using the following code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.scrollViewOutlet.minimumZoomScale=0.5;

    self.scrollViewOutlet.maximumZoomScale=4.0;

    self.scrollViewOutlet.contentSize=self.imagetobeZoomed.image.size;

    self.scrollViewOutlet.clipsToBounds=YES;

    self.scrollViewOutlet.delegate=self;

}

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{


    return self.imagetobeZoomed;
}
```

By using the code above I am able to zoom the image , but my problem is my image runs to the bottom left corner on zooming . That is I am not able to keep my image position fixed to the center of the screen.

I want image position to be remain fixed on zooming . Any help on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution  my self.Here is complete code sample for image zoom :) Here the image position remains fixed on zooming in and out .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.scrollViewOutlet.minimumZoomScale=0.5;
    self.scrollViewOutlet.maximumZoomScale=4.0;
    self.scrollViewOutlet.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.imagetobeZoomed.frame.size.width,       self.imagetobeZoomed.frame.size.height);
    self.scrollViewOutlet.clipsToBounds=YES;
    self.scrollViewOutlet.delegate=self;
}

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imagetobeZoomed;
}


-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{   
    UIView *subView=[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    CGFloat offsetX = (scrollView.bounds.size.width > scrollView.contentSize.width)? 
    (scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5 : 0.0;
    CGFloat offsetY = (scrollView.bounds.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height)? 
(scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5 : 0.0;
     subView.center = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX, 
                             scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY);

}
```

Comment: I am using pinch gesture for Zoom in/out image view. But i want when scale of image view is more then screen size then scrolling process occur.But UISCrollViewDelegate method can not call even i set delegate to scroll view in nib file.

Comment: Th above code works perfectly fine for zooming and when the scale of image view is more then screen size then scrolling process also occurs

Comment: May be , try setting the scroll view delegate once again

Comment: Tried so many time also put break point and log to detect method call but it can not call.

Comment: can you post your code ? and are using gesture recognizer ? the code I posted above works fine for pinch zoom , just using a scrollview without using any of the gesture recognizers

Comment: But i am using pinch gesture for zooming image view. And problem is scrollViewDidScroll method of delegate is called but viewForZoomingInScrollView method is not called

Comment: Thats really strange . As far as I know both these methods should get called after setting the delegate properly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18451/discussion-between-leena-and-raj)

Comment: I understand my mistake.Thanks for your code i am using your code for this.

Comment: happy to help :)I was out of my desk . so couldn't  reply instantly. btw what was your mistake ?

Comment: Mistake is i am using pinch gesture and scroll view both in one process. So thats why its not working properly. So finally i remove pinch gesture and only use your code that's work completely. Now i need your another help. Can you help me second time??

Comment: Yea sure if its possible from my side .

Comment: Sorry i did not show your message.Today I will surely mail code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18557/discussion-between-leena-and-raj)

Answer (score 1):

Just try [NYOBetterZoom](https://github.com/nyoron/NYOBetterZoom). This is your answer for sure. :)

Comment: I will check it once and get back to you.

Comment: Is there any other sample which I can follow? Because I feel the sample provided is bit complex to understand for me as I am a beginner now.

Comment: As i said I am able to zoom using my code. The only problem is I am not able to keep the image position fixed.

Comment: The solution worked fine , but I found even simpler solution.